# Как вызывать событие в дискорд боте при подключении к новому серверу python

Tags: python, discord, бот

Если кратко, я хочу что бы бот создавал текстовый чат при подключении к новому серверу, но нигде не нашел такого события(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import json

from discord.ext import commands


class InviteTracker(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        bot.loop.create_task(self.load())

    async def load(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        return await self.send_log("Started")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        return await self.send_log("JOIN: {member}")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_remove(self, member):
        return await self.send_log("LEAVE: {member}")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        return await self.send_log(f"Joined to guild: {guild.name}")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_remove(self, guild):
        return await self.send_log(f"Leave from guild: {guild.name}")

    async def send_log(self, message):
        Log.create(message=message)
        await self.logs_channel.send(message)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(InviteTracker(bot, redis))
```